# How to check if TextBox.Text is round number?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to check, that my TextBox contains round number, even like in this format: "5.00"

I tryed Integer.TryParse(), but it returns False. It works just in that case, when the TextBox contains the number like in this format: "5"

Comment: check for the presence of "." or other decimal separators?

Comment: Don't use a TextBox?  How about a NumericUpDown instead?  Then you can control it better...

Comment: Type values like your users do in Hungary, not like a programmer does.  So "5,00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your string number to `Double`  and then check using `Math.Round()` method

```
//Convert to Double && round double number and check with original double number
if((Double.TryParse(textValue, out double number)) && Math.Round(number) == number)
{
 //Here you go;
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zlkkdE)

Comment: Thanks for the fine tip! In my VB.NET code it looks like this: `Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(Replace(TextBox.Text, ".", ","))
z = Math.Round(d)

If d = z Then
...`

Comment: @Levo, because of floating point math, this solution does not work with an input of  "n.9999999999999999". I don't care about the rep points, but if you only need to consider integral values then I suggest you use the built-in functionality of `int.TryParse` which also gives you the advantage of handling different cultures.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of `Parse` that accepts a NumberStyle

```
var i = int.Parse("5.00", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Or `TryParse`

```
int.TryParse("5.00", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, null, out int nbr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
Function IsRound(sNr As String) As Boolean
    Return IsNumeric(sNr) AndAlso Decimal.Truncate(CDec(sNr)) = CDec(sNr)
End Function
```